# Order the columns of a file using sed with node.js

Tags: node.js

I have a large file, separated by say a tab or a comma as a delimeter. I want to rearrange the columns of this file in any specific order dynamically. I have tried sed commands. It works well on command line but trying with nodes exec, it does not work.

Command used on command line: (for tab separated file)
ordering the columns in 3,1,2 order

```
sed -i -e 's@\(.*\)\t\(.*\)\t\(.*\)@\3\t\1\t\2@g' file_tab_header.txt

sed -i -e 's/\(.*\)\t\(.*\)\t\(.*\)/\3\t\1\t\2/' file_tab_header.txt
```

The above command works well on command line.

---

### Sample node js code:-

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var command = "sed -i -e 's@\(.*\)\\t\(.*\)\\t\(.*\)@\3\\t\1\\t\2@g' file_tab_header.txt";

var command = "sed -i -e 's/\(.*\)\\t\(.*\)\\t\(.*\)/\3\\t\1\\t\2/' file_tab_header.txt";

child = exec(

command, function (error, stdout, stderr) {});
```

I have tried many variations but none of them work with exec. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks[image]

Comment: When you say it doesn t work, what do you mean? STDERR get something? The file doesn t change? Change in another way? Callback never get called?

Comment: @DrakaSAN Hi, The expected result is, that the file should be modified. The column should be rearranged according to the order mentioned. But it doesn't. It does not show any error.

Comment: Could you provide a example input file, and the expected result for that input file?

Comment: @DrakaSAN, I was unable to post what I wanted, so I have added an image in the question above. Please check that. The input and  its desired output. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using a script like that:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    file = './test.txt',
    //order = [2, 1, 0],
    separator = ' ';

function parse_line(lines, order, separator, callback, i, output) {
    if(!i) {i = 0;}
    if(!output) {output = '';}
    console.log('line: ' + lines[i]);
    var line,
        j = 0,
        o = [],
        s = '';

    if (i < lines.length) {
        line = lines[i].split(separator);
        while (j < line.length) {
            o[order[j]] = line[j].trim();
            j = j + 1;
        }
        s = o.join(separator);
        console.log('+> ' + s);
        output = output + s + '\n';
        parse_line(lines, order, separator, callback, i + 1, output);
    } else {
        callback(output);
    }
}

function parse_file(file, order, separator, callback) {
    fs.readFile(file, function (err, data) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            callback(null);
        } else {
            data = '' + data;

            lines = String(data).split('\n');
            parse_line(lines, order, separator, function (output) {
                callback(output);
            });
        }
    });
}

function get_order(callback) {
    var i = 2,
        order = [];
    while (i < process.argv.length) {
        order.push(parseInt(process.argv[i]));
        i = i + 1;
    }
    callback(order);
}

get_order (function (order) {
    parse_file(file, order, separator, function (output) {
        console.log(output);
    });
});
```

Not thorougly tested, and doesn t adress the issue with sed, but can be used as a workaround.

EDIT:

test file:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

result:

```
E:\Documents\GIT\stackoverflow>node test.js 0 1 2
line: 1 2 3
+> 1 2 3
line: 4 5 6
+> 4 5 6
line: 7 8 9
+> 7 8 9
line: undefined
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9


E:\Documents\GIT\stackoverflow>node test.js 1 2 0
line: 1 2 3
+> 3 1 2
line: 4 5 6
+> 6 4 5
line: 7 8 9
+> 9 7 8
line: undefined
3 1 2
6 4 5
9 7 8


E:\Documents\GIT\stackoverflow>node test.js 2 1 0
line: 1 2 3
+> 3 2 1
line: 4 5 6
+> 6 5 4
line: 7 8 9
+> 9 8 7
line: undefined
3 2 1
6 5 4
9 8 7


E:\Documents\GIT\stackoverflow>node test.js 0 2 1
line: 1 2 3
+> 1 3 2
line: 4 5 6
+> 4 6 5
line: 7 8 9
+> 7 9 8
line: undefined
1 3 2
4 6 5
7 9 8
```

Comment: Thanks @DrakaSAN, I will check the above code. In case if any one else can look into the sed option with node, it will be of great help.

Comment: Hello @DrakaSAN, I used your code, but it doesn't work every time. It works for order 0,1,2. 0,2,1. But when I change it to 2,1,0 or 1,2,0 it doesn't work. :(

Comment: Just tried it, work for me. It just print thought, you need to write the file if that was the problem

Comment: Hi @DrakaSAN, I crossed checked it again. It doesn't work for order 1 2 0 

    line: 1 2 3

    Output should be 2 3 1, but it shows 3 1 2

Comment: Hi @DrakaSAN, I found this module https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-column-reorder. this works as expected. but the only issue is that browser shows aborted status if the script is called through ajax. I want to call the functionality on button click. Please suggest what can be done. Thanks